# How do you bind windows together in a Cocoa Application so they resize together?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I am attempting my first Cocoa Application after developing for iOS for the past few years. I have been "googling" around for awhile now but I guess I am not using the correct terminology to find what I am looking for.

In many applications OSX applications I see this little dot (or sometimes no dot at all like in XCode) which allows you to grab "an invisble" line? Which will resize two or three windows at a time while they are all bound together. How is this done? I'd like to implement it in my current app I am building. I have attached an image to clarify what I am talking about.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are not windows. These are subviews of an NSSplitView

Answer (score 0):

It's an [`NSSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  The line is the *divider* and can have 3 different styles:

```
NSSplitViewDividerStyleThick = 1,
NSSplitViewDividerStyleThin = 2,
NSSplitViewDividerStylePaneSplitter = 3,
```

(the style in the images of your question are the *Pane Splitter* style).

The content views can be easily added using Interface Builder, or programmatically using the `[NSView addSubview:]` method (`NSSplitView` derives from `NSView`).

You will want to control the splitter behaviour via its delegate ([`NSSplitViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSSplitViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSSplitViewDelegate)).

Also note that the image in your question appears to show a split view within another split view, which is a fairly common way of laying out views.